# In Bat file, how do I ignore output of call command

Tags: batch-file

I am calling another bat file from my bat file.  I don't really care for it's output.  How do I ignore them so it doesn't show up in my bat file output?  For example:

File A

```
echo File A Starting
call FileB
echo File A Finished
```

File B

```
echo In File B
```

So what I currently get:

```
File A Starting
In FIle B
File A Finished
```

What I want:

```
File A Starting
File A Finished
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to hide result of `call FileB`, then redirect stdout and stderr to **nul**: `call FileB > nul 2>&1` .

If you wish to hide the command itself, toggle @ECHO before and after calling it:

```
@ECHO OFF
call FileB > nul 2>&1
@ECHO ON
```

Comment: what does 2>&1 do?

Comment: @Bill Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) which explains also `2>&1`.

Comment: Although link provided by @Mofi should be enough, I'm just summarizing here:
        `> nul` -> redirects stdout (1) to nul;
        `2>&1` -> redirects stderr (2) to stdout (1) handle